# Active Model Serializer with Ember - how to add an element to the collection

Tags: ember.js, ruby-on-rails-5, ember-data

I have 2 models `Country` and `Language` linked with HABTM relation.
I'm using Rails API with ActiveModelSerializer and Ember JS as frontend.
So how is it possible to add a new `language` to `country.languages` collection ?

On the Ember side I'm trying to add a new language as follows:

```
#router

actions: {
saveLanguage(language) {
      let controller = this.get('controller');
      let country = controller.get('aCountry');
      country.get('languages').pushObject(language);
      country.save();
    }
}
```

This calls `CountriesController#update` action in Rails.
Here is how I deserialize `params` hash in Rails controller:

```
#countries_controller.rb

    def country_params
      ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(params)
    end
```

And here is what it returns:

```
{:code=>"BE", :name=>"BELGIUM", :modified_by=>"XXX", :id=>"5", :language_ids=>["374", "231", "69"]}
```

So I'm getting all I need:

```
country ID => id=5
languages IDS => both existing ones (2) and a new one.
```

How to properly update the country ? Thank you.

Comment: The only way I found is to use `update` method: `country.update(language_ids: [374, 231, 69])` and testing the returned result (`true` if saved, `false` otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out hot to add/delete an item to/from a association.
So on Ember side it looks like that:

```
actions: {
    deleteLanguage(language) {
      let controller = this.get('controller');
      let country = controller.get('aCountry');

      country.get('languages').removeObject(language);
      country.set('modifiedBy', this.get('currentUser.user').get('username'))
      country.save();
    },

    saveLanguage(language) {
      let controller = this.get('controller');
      let country = controller.get('aCountry');
      country.get('languages').pushObject(language);
      country.set('modifiedBy', this.get('currentUser.user').get('username'))
      country.save();
    }
```

And on the Rails side everything happens in the `CountriesController`:

```
class CountriesController < ApplicationController
...
def update
      if @country.update(country_params)
        json_response @country
      else
        json_response @country.errors, :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    private
    def find_country
      @country = Country.includes(:languages).find(params[:id])
    end

    def country_params
      ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(params,
        only: [
          :id,
          :modified_by,
          :languages
        ])
    end
end
```

Sure, I'll have to add some errors handling on Ember side just to display a confirmation of the update or the errors.

Method `json_response` is just my custom helper defined as follows in `concerns` for controllers:

```
module Response
  def json_response(object, status = :ok, opts = {})
    response = {json: object, status: status}.merge(opts)
    render response
  end
end
```

Hope this helps. You can find more about mode relations in [Ember Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/relationships/).